# Load shipping rates on click instead of page load on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods, speedoptimization

One of my website's cart page is slow and after some digging up I found that the shipping-rates.html is taking up time to load. Is there any way, through which instead of implicitly loading I can load it when clicked on button, as this will reduce the time and of cart page load time. I have explored and found that shipping-rate.js is responsible for loading the html, can we do it without first time loading it. Even smallest of help will be appreciated.